# Design a file system

Tags: design-patterns, filesystems

What should be the classes that one needs to create while designing a file system . What kind of of design patterns should be used in designing the file system.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it being homework, is there?

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit: nothing wrong, I just added proper tag.

Comment: Ah. Didn't know there was one :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow.com! Please be aware that this site is meant for specific questions with a specific answer. Your question is much too vague to have a meaningful answer. Please edit it to change this; othwerwise it will be closed shortly.

Comment: If you tell us what you already have then there will be more willing persons to reply to your question.

Comment: @Sergi: Read [this meta-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/) regarding homework questions.

Comment: @Sergi: For the record: I didn't want to create the impression that asking homework questions is wrong. I just was not sure whether the homework tag should be applied.

Comment: @musiKk - I gathered as much after reading the rest of comments, but I must admit that I misinterpreted your intentions. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 19):

If you're really looking for a list of design patterns to apply when designing a file system, you should consider

- [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) for modelling directories/files
- [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for allowing to associate additional properties (and possibly behaviour) to file system nodes.
- [Iterator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) for traversing the file system in different ways
- [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) for creating file system nodes with different backends (e.g. a disk-based file system or a memory-based file system or a remote file system).

I think that this general approach of trying to apply all the patterns you can is wrong though, it's easy to overengineer your software like that. The key insight with design patterns is to realize when you should *not* apply a pattern.

Comment: Great answer . I was actually thinking that composite makes sense to have folders as composite objects (which will have leaves) and files as leaf objects . But I am not able to relate how decorator and iterator can be used here .

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like homework. However, check out at least the following patterns:

- [Composite](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite) (files/directories)
- [Proxy](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/proxy) (symbolic links)
- [Iterator](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/iterator) (to traverse the FS)

You should as well google for "filesystem design patterns" to find lots of examples. Finally, read a good [introduction to design patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns).

Comment: I am not able to get any good links where I can see good examples

Comment: plus-1 for the introduction link